# Discrete Multivariate Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

A fair six-sided die is rolled, showing a number of dots N ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. Then N fair dice are rolled. Let X be the average of the numbers shown on the N dice.

a) Find E[NX]

b) Prove whether or not X and N are independent

For part a I got 12.25, but I am unsure if that is correct or how to approach part b.

Comment: Can you explain how you got $12.25$ for part *a* ?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were giving the value for 1 roll, sorry. What you computed is perfectly ok, using linearity of expectation

Comment: What are the possible values of $X$ when $N=1$? when $N=2$? etc